# C++ template with condition for type

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I have class with template. I want to add template condition for one of the class methods.

The idea is for float types I want separate *passed* method to call this with some epsillon value.

Is it possible? The example what I want:

```
template<typename ValueType>
class Comparator {
public:

...

bool passed(ValueType actualValue);

template<
    typename ValueType,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_floating_point<std::remove_reference_t<ValueType>>::value
    >
>
bool passed(ValueType actualValue, ValueType eps) { ... }

...

};
```

Environment:
Debian 11,
C++14,
gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110

Comment: you have the wrong approach define two function , then when calling use type_trait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most of the way there already.  In order to overload SFINAE, you need to use a non-type template parameter with an assigned default value instead of using defaulted type template parameter.

So, we change both functions to use a non-type paramere with a default value, and just negate the condition like:

```
template<typename ValueType>
class Comparator {
public:

...
template<
    typename T = ValueType,
    std::enable_if_t<
        !std::is_floating_point<std::remove_reference_t<ValueType>>::value,
//      ^- not here, so only non-floating point types allowed
        bool> = true // set the bool to true, this lets us call the function without providing a value for it
>
bool passed(T actualValue) { non floating point code here }

template<
    typename T = ValueType,
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_floating_point<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value,
        bool> = true // set the bool to true, this lets us call the function without providing a value for it
>
bool passed(T actualValue, T eps) { floating point code here }
```

Comment: @Elliott It might be, but I'm not sure.  From what I have seen the non-type template parameter version seems to be more widely used.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you for the reply. Could you please describe, what mean this "bool> = true // set the bool to true, this lets us call the function without providing a value for it"?

Comment: @ВалентинНикин Without the `= true` part, you would have to call the function like `foo.passed<type_of_parameter, true>(parameter)`.  By having the `= true`, we set the bool variables that `std::enable_if_t` resolves to to `true`, which means we can call the function like `foo.passed(parameter)`

Comment: @ВалентинНикин, these SFINAE techniques are a compiler hack. It has the exact same effect if you write `= false` . It's just a default to a nameless type argument.

Comment: Not work for `Comparator<float>{}.passed(0, 0);`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 which is the correct behavior.  `0` is an `int`, which is not a floating point type.  You would need `Comparator<float>{}.passed(0.0, 0.0);`

Comment: @NathanOliver. are you sure about that? So what's the point of explicitly specifying `float`? This is obviously inconvenient and not the intention of the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename ValueType>
class Comparator {
public:

template<
    typename U = ValueType,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<
        !std::is_floating_point<std::remove_reference_t<U>>::value
    >
>
bool passed(ValueType actualValue);

template<
    typename U = ValueType,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_floating_point<std::remove_reference_t<U>>::value
    >
>
bool passed(ValueType actualValue, ValueType eps);

};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/xT4qeebG1)

Comment: [This can be hacked](https://godbolt.org/z/YYKrsjasM). Better to use a value default like `enable_if_t<blah, int> = 0`, which [can't be hacked](https://godbolt.org/z/e488T3dEW).